# form submitting with onLoad input values instead of user inputted values when automated with VBA

Tags: html, forms, vba, excel, internet-explorer-11

Main Issue: When I submit a form using vba, the form's inputs' values change unexpectedly. I'm looking to see if there's an issue I don't know of with document.forms().submit in vba that might be related?

Code first, explanation follows:

```
htmlwindow.Document.getElementById("ReportNum_DropDownList").selectedIndex = 15
htmlwindow.Document.getElementById("ToMMYY_TextBox").Value = QtrMo & "/" & QtrYr
htmlwindow.Document.getElementById("FromMMYY_TextBox").Value = QtrMo_min2 & "/" & QtrYr
htmlwindow.Document.getElementById("ReportCols_DropDownList").selectedIndex = 2
htmlwindow.Document.getElementById("__EVENTTARGET").Value = "Display"
htmlwindow.Document.forms("Form1").submit
```

Using vba in excel I open IE, navigate to a login page and login, then arrive at "Reports" page which has "Form1", which has several  elements.

When the Reports page loads, all of Form1's inputs have pre-loaded values from the last time I used the website.  For instance input "FromMMYY_TextBox" is a text box that already reads "08/15" when the Reports page loads.  I have several lines of code that update the inputs, including "FromMMYY_TextBox".  Then I submit the form, and when it submits, it ignores the new values in the inputs and uses the pre-loaded values that populated the inputs upon originally loading the page.  So if I made "FromMMYY_TextBox".Value = "09/15", it submits as "08/15" for some reason.

There is no "on_submit" in the  element.  I also tried to clear history/cookies/form submissions/passwords/etc from IE and do this, but when the Reports page loads, the inputs are still pre-populated.  When I use ".click" on Form1's submit button, I have a more "intense" problem so that's ruled out as an option I think.

Is there anything strange about document.forms().submit that might cause this?  Or should I try to see if I'm tripping some kind of validation code?  I'm lost on what could cause this.

Edit: When I use ".click" on the Form's submit button, the form submits with the correct input values, but it will not display in the browser like it should. Instead it attempts to download the table as an excel file, which I do not want.

Edit2: I turned off auto-complete in IE and it did not help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! I recommend you should edit your question to include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - this will help others to understand your problem and to help you arrive at a solution. It looks like the problem you are trying to resolve is somewhat complex and involves a number of moving parts. Also, it is not entirely clear what your actual issue is. It might be also helpful to review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Could IE be using AutoFill? Try disabling it.